# Can't test website with google page speed insight

Tags: google-chrome, performance-testing, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am wondering why I can't test my website with this tools.

I thought at first that it's just some temporary network or server issues, but this happening for more than 2 weeks already.

I have no clue what may cause this.

With Other testing websites it works normaly

[image: PageSpeed Insight]

[image: Think with Google]

Comment: Maybe website response time is too much. some third party are not responding.

Comment: what can I do then ?

Comment: send me domain name ? I can guide you

Comment: Well, your theme is not optimized and not responding. So first disable current theme, and select default theme and then try this speed tool. Then we can debug.

Comment: i am currently working on the optimization (css js images...) but I can not disable the them otherwise it will break the website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130765/discussion-between-naveed-ramzan-and-test404).